# Measurable Characteristic Function

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable. Let $A \in \mathcal{B}$ be a Borel set and $B = X^{-1}(A)$. I want to prove that $\chi_B$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(X)$.

$\textbf{My attempt:}$ Since $\chi_B=\chi_A\circ X$ is the composition of measurable functions, $\chi_B$ is measurable. $X$ is measurable by definition. $\chi_A$ is measurable if and only if $A$ is measurable.

How do I show A is a measurable set?

Comment: A measurable set in $\mathbb R$ is nothing but  a Borel set.There is nothing to prove here.